# Inverse DCT via DFT formula deduction

Tags: dft, dct

## Context

I am reading this book [Discrete Cosine Transform [...]. K.R. Rao and P.YIP. 1990](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/645332146).

**Given That**

From `Equation (2.4.11.a)`

$$
X^{C(2)}(m) = \left ( \frac{2}{N} \right )^{1/2} k_m \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x(n) \cos \left [ \frac{(2n+1)m \pi}{2N} \right ]
$$

$m=0, ..., N-1$

Here, we have

$$
k_p =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \text{when } p = 0 \text{ or } N \\
1 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

From Book's `Equation (2.8.7)`

$$
F^{C(2)}(k) = k_k \exp \left [ \frac{-j \pi k}{2N} \right ] \hat{F}_F(k)
$$

Here, we have

$$
k_p =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & p = 0 \\
1 & p = 1, ..., N-1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

**Now Comes the following**

> It is not difficult to show that the sequence $f(n)$ can be recovered from the transformed sequence $F^{C(2)}(k)$, as as a result we have

From `(Equation 2.8.8)`

$$
f(n) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \Re \left \{ \sum^{2N-1}_{k=0} k_k F^{C(2)} \exp \left [ \frac{j \pi k}{2N} \right ] \exp \left [ \frac{2j \pi k n}{2N} \right ] \right \}
$$

$n=0, ..., N-1$

---

## Question

1. I do not understand how that $k_k$ is present on the `(2.8.8)`. If I had to deduct this equation myself from `(2.8.7)` $k_k$ would pop on the other side of the equality inverted, as $k_k$, though it would yield a division by zero. But I could pretend `(2.8.7)` uses the same definition for as `(2.4.11.a)` resulting on a $F^{C(2)}(k)$ that is defined for $k > N-1$, then $k_k^{-1}$ wouldn't yield division by zero. How is `(2.8.8)` actually obtained?
2. Why having two different definitions for $k_k$?

Comment: The two definitions of $k_k$ are equivalent in the range $0..N$ though (?)

Comment: Indeed they are. However, I am kind of using a different version of the iDCT that uses the first definition, the second one wouldn't be suitable as I said in the question. Though I am not sure why the book does what it does.